# JPA store properties as rows

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, jpa

I have configuration object.

```
Config {
  String a;
  int b;
....
}

Config2 {
  Double c;
....
}
```

Since only one config object is in system, i want to store as rows.

all properties name as key

```
key  value   type
a    test    config
b    123     config
aa   11.11   config2
```

Is there a way to do this in JPA ?What is best pattern to store such object ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in multiple ways, here is a sample one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "YOURTABLE")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue("config")
Config {
  @Id
  String key;
  @Column(name = "type")
  String type;
  @Transient 
  String a;
  @Transient 
  int b;
  ....
  @Column(name ="value")
  String value ;

  initType ()
  {
    // assume either a or b contain value
    value = a == null || a.isEmpty() ? String.valueOf(a) : a;
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "YOURTABLE")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@DiscriminatorValue("config2")
Config2 {

  @Id
  String key;
  @Column(name = "type")
  String type;
  @Transient
  Double c;
  @Column(name ="value")
  String value ;
  ....
  initType ()
  {
    value = String.valueOf(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: This can't work as is because it will require DB field 'a' and 'b', and will return multiple config objects when only one is desired.

Comment: @Chris not needed. a & be can be transient, look my code both are wrapped into 'type'. Also I said this is one way.

Comment: @Chris Can you elaborate a bit ..."//assume either a or b contain value" ..In my case Config is one complete object so all of them will contain some value.

Comment: @JigarShah you did not understand my logic?

Comment: @JigarShah there will still be one Config entity for each row with a type = config in the database instead of only one.

Answer (score 0):

You might try creating a property entity, and then having Config and Config2 contain methods that can build themselves from a list of properties or a factory to do it.

```
List<Property> configPropeties = entityManager.createQuery("select p from Property p where p.type='config'").getResultList();
Config config = new Config();
for(Property p: configProperty) {
  if (p.key == "a")
    config.a = P.value;
..
```

You can probably use reflection to make it even more generic, since the key will be an attribute within the object, and the type used in the query can be determined from the class name.  Persisting changes requires reversing the process and merging the properties into the entityManager.  Property will need a compound pk using key and type.